# How to use data from View in method which creates PDF file

Tags: .net, pdf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method which filters data from my database and a View that shows the data.

I'd like to have a button in the View which triggers creation of a PDF from the filtered data.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to work on something similar not too long ago and blogged about it here:
http://www.megustaulises.com/2012/12/mvcnet-convert-html-to-pdf-with-pechkin.html

In a few words the main idea is to use a view to display your data and then have a controller action method that will render its html and finally pass it to a tool that will render this html as a PDF file.

Comment: Hii Thanks for help. I was trying to use it but i need more time. Meanwhile i found something like this which can help others http://www.kristofclaes.be/blog/2011/11/18/using-a-filestreamresult-with-a-memorystream-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Comment: The utility used in the blog "wkhtmltopdf" is free and works like a charm though. Good luck.